# Spring Custom formatter not being called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-rest

I am working on a rest api using spring framework. 
All my attempts to get a custom formatter working with spring-boot have yielded no results. 
The custom Annotation formatter should format a LocalDate, LocalDateTime and Dates.

Even the pre-existing spring formatters ( @DateTimeFormat, @NumberFormat ) do not work.

This post [Spring: custom validator is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773500/spring-custom-validator-is-not-being-called) is similar but I haven't noticed any mismatch in my code.

The examples online regarding custom formatters use jsp's to get the value. Can they be used in a spring rest based projects rather than mvc ? Probably the way I am using the formatter is incorrect.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

```
public class BroadcastDateFormatter implements Formatter<LocalDate>
{

@Override
public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale)
    throws ParseException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

} 


public class BroadcastLocalDateFormatterAnnotationFactory implements     AnnotationFormatterFactory<BroadcastLocalDateFormat>
{

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes()
{
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    classes.add(LocalDate.class);
    classes.add(LocalDateTime.class);
    classes.add(Date.class);
    return classes;
}

@Override
public Printer<?> getPrinter(BroadcastLocalDateFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType)
{
    return new BroadcastDateFormatter();
}

@Override
public Parser<?> getParser(BroadcastLocalDateFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType)
{
    return new BroadcastDateFormatter();
}

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.*" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.test.*" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class AppConfig
extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addConverter(new FilterExpressionConverter());
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new BroadcastLocalDateFormatterAnnotationFactory());
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new SSNAnnotationFormatterFactory());
    registry.addFormatter(new SSNFormatter());
    registry.addFormatter(new BroadcastDateFormatter());
}


public class FooDomain
{
@JsonProperty(value="my_current_date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-d")
private LocalDate currentDate;

@BroadcastLocalDateFormat
private LocalDate broadcastDate;

@NumberFormat(style=Style.CURRENCY, pattern = "#,###.###")
private Double currency;
}


output: 
{
      "string": "foo",
      "lng": 1,
      "integer": 1,
      "dbl": 1.2,
      "flt": 1.3,
      "bigDecimal": 1.1,
      "innerClass": {
        "string": "foo",
        "lng": 1,
        "integer": 1,
        "dbl": 1.2,
        "flt": 1.3,
        "bigDecimal": 1.1
      },
      "innerClassesList": [
        {
          "string": "foo",
          "lng": 1,
          "integer": 1,
          "dbl": 1.2,
          "flt": 1.3,
          "bigDecimal": 1.1
        },
        {
          "string": "foo",
          "lng": 1,
          "integer": 1,
          "dbl": 1.2,
          "flt": 1.3,
          "bigDecimal": 1.1
        }
      ],
      "innerClassSet": [
        {
          "string": "foo",
          "lng": 1,
          "integer": 1,
          "dbl": 1.2,
          "flt": 1.3,
          "bigDecimal": 1.1
        },
        {
          "string": "foo",
          "lng": 1,
          "integer": 1,
          "dbl": 1.2,
          "flt": 1.3,
          "bigDecimal": 1.1
        }
      ],
      "innerClassMap": {
        "1": {
          "string": "foo",
          "lng": 1,
          "integer": 1,
          "dbl": 1.2,
          "flt": 1.3,
          "bigDecimal": 1.1
        }
      },
      "someEnum": "FOO",
      "someObject": null,
      "bigDecimalPct": 1.1,
      "currency": 1001.3,
      "javUtilDate": "2017-01-16 20:20 PM UTC",
      "broadcastDate": [
        2017,
        1,
        16
      ],
      "broadcastDateTime": [
        2017,
        1,
        16,
        15,
        20,
        43,
        7000000
      ],
      "ssn": {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "b"
      },
      "my_current_date": "2017-01-16"
    }
```